# Custom post type not using custom template

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

So I've been working on a WordPress site, and I need a custom post for documents, which is supposed to be registered as 'document'. I generated the code for the custom post in a plugin, Meta Box, and placed the code in my functions.php file (though while testing, I disabled Meta Box to see if it was interfering, while keeping the php it generated in functions.php). I have a template, single-document.php file, in the root of my theme (which is a child theme, if that makes a difference). But WordPress keeps defaulting to single.php, even after refreshing permalinks.

This is the code Meta Box generated to add the custom post:

```php
function register_document() {

    $args = array (
        'label' => esc_html__( 'Documents', 'mb86' ),
        'labels' => array(
            'menu_name' => esc_html__( 'Documents', 'mb86' ),
            'name_admin_bar' => esc_html__( 'Document', 'mb86' ),
            'add_new' => esc_html__( 'Add new', 'mb86' ),
            'add_new_item' => esc_html__( 'Add new Document', 'mb86' ),
            'new_item' => esc_html__( 'New Document', 'mb86' ),
            'edit_item' => esc_html__( 'Edit Document', 'mb86' ),
            'view_item' => esc_html__( 'View Document', 'mb86' ),
            'update_item' => esc_html__( 'Update Document', 'mb86' ),
            'all_items' => esc_html__( 'All Documents', 'mb86' ),
            'search_items' => esc_html__( 'Search Documents', 'mb86' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => esc_html__( 'Parent Document', 'mb86' ),
            'not_found' => esc_html__( 'No Documents found', 'mb86' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => esc_html__( 'No Documents found in Trash', 'mb86' ),
            'name' => esc_html__( 'Documents', 'mb86' ),
            'singular_name' => esc_html__( 'Document', 'mb86' ),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'description' => 'Handbooks, manuals, and other documents.',
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-book-alt',
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite_no_front' => false,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'thumbnail',
        ),
        'rewrite' => true,
    );

    register_post_type( 'document', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_document' );
```

Since most topics addressing this issue focus updating permalinks (which I've repeatedly tried), I'm not really sure how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be your parent theme has hard coded way to call templates and overriding the wp standard templating?

Comment: The parent theme is Storefront, if that makes a difference

Comment: To list posts, do you have something like a template tpl-document.php ?

Comment: Anyway, look at this https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere along the line, a .php file got changed to a .txt file, and after changing the extension to .php, everything worked fine.